# H1 text off-center on load, gets pushed down several pixels. Only displays properly after mouseover

Tags: css, html

The text below appears off-center upon page load. It only readjusts after mousing over the elements. Why does this happen?

To reproduce live (happens on Chrome), visit http://www.panabee.com/name-generator?domain-name=cool

Page load screenshot:

[image]

On mouseover screenshot:

[image]

HTML:

```
   <div class="header">
                    <h1>
                        Domain Names
                    </h1>
                    <div class="tld_select hover_rise">
                        .<span class="default_tld">com</span> <div class="arrow"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tooltip right in" style="">
                        <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">Find free domains with other extensions</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shift_taken"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on firefox

Comment: I also cant reproduce this on my firefox or chrome.

Comment: hmmm, odd. this happens consistently on windows 7 home premium using chrome.

Comment: Works fine on my Chrome Version 32.0.1700.102 @Crashalot

Comment: Chrome 32.0.1700.102 can't duplicate error.

Comment: @ruddy, which operating system are you using?

Comment: which OS, @WBOCo, are you using?

Comment: what happens if you search for "cool" instead of "cool picture"

Comment: OS X 10.9.1 so you've got a pretty good spread here.

Comment: @Crashalot That did it. Search "cool" and it does it. So it only happens after searching.

Comment: "cool" did it for me on load and then fixed itself before mouseover.

Comment: awesome, now hopefully you know the reason why this happens, too :)

Comment: Can't repro on IE 11.

Comment: @user-12506, try searching for "cool" instead of "cool picture"

Comment: @WBOCo. any clue why it happens on page load? btw love the clean, simple design of your site. sorry about the broncos.

Comment: @Crashalot thanks. Done. Still can't reproduce on IE 11: http://imgur.com/y4Iqsx9

Comment: @user-12506 looks like it only happens on chrome. thanks for trying though.

Comment: @Crashalot I might have to do some reading up on it but I believe it has to do with the order in which the browser is rendering your elements. Changing even the text color in CSS (using developer tools) fixes the problem because I believe it then re-renders the objects.

Comment: @Crashalot Its going to be very hard to fine what's causing it as I have to reload the page every time to get it to happen. Shall we just try recoding that bit? If you get the HTML and CSS we can have a look at another way to do it. Maybe instead of `inline-block` we can float it. See if it changes.

Comment: cool, please post whatever you find as an answer so we can credit you! thanks again!

Comment: sure the HTML is posted already, lemme post the CSS.

Comment: I suggest that you set some widths for all elements in the header, this may fix the problem. It does seem to be rendering in that line a bit odd as if you do **anything** to the `h1` it seems to fix it self.

Comment: Whatever is causing the rendering problems I'm pretty sure it's caused by the "." outside of your default_tld span. Is it possible for you to place that inside the span? Also why are there quotes around the period. Am I missing something?

Comment: Would it help to give `white-space:nowrap` to `div.tld_select`?

Comment: @WBOCo., there are no quotes in the HTML above, probably only in the chrome dev console. we put the period inside its own span but to no avail. any other ideas?

Comment: @MrLister didn't help unfortunately. any other ideas?

Comment: it seems solved now. could you guys try it and see if it still happens? the solution was to pre-populate the default TLD value as it's empty by default. if someone could post this as the solution, we'll award the answer to one of you guys for trying to help us solve the question!

Comment: @WBOCo. forgot to include you in the earlier comment

Comment: @Ruddy forgot to include you in the earlier comment

Comment: I can confirm this has been fixed, good job. You can post an answer on your own question as mark it as correct. We didn't do much but guess what was wrong. @Crashalot